# Angular: Scroll to container after ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have a radio group with an embodiment of "Yes / No". After selecting "Yes" appears container with the text. I want to happen scroll to new container.

html:

```
<li ng-repeat="q in vm.model.questions">
    <ng-form name="myForm">
        <md-radio-group ng-model="q.answer" layout="row" required class='radio_group'>
            <md-radio-button ng-value="true" aria-label="Yes">Yes</md-radio-button>
            <md-radio-button ng-value="false" aria-label="No">No</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
        <md-input-container flex ng-if="vm.blockRequired(q)">
            <label>{{'q.text'}}</label>
        </md-input-container>
    </ng-form>
</li>
```

controller:

```
  function blockRequired(question) {
        return question.answer === true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're injecting $location and $anchorScroll into your controller and then in your function use something like:

```
$location.hash(id);
$anchorScroll();
```

Where id represents the id of the item you want to scroll to. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll for details.

Comment: But blockRequired function is called for all objects in ng-repeat. I need to when you select "Yes" in a particular block to open the container with text and scroll to this container

Comment: Then you need to use ng-click on the yes button or ngChange on the radio group and respond to when yes is clicked. You haven't posted nearly enough detail or code to get a more helpful answer.